# Nginx serves raw php

Tags: nginx, php

I have PHP-FPM setup listening on 127.0.0.1:9000 properly on Ubuntu, it seems to spawn everything properly, my nginx works great for plain html as well, this is nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

This is the actual server:

```
    server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  localhost;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
            root html;

            location ~ \.php$ {
               fastcgi_index   index.php;
               fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
               include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
               fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
            }
    }
```

I have tried different configs for the server yet the result is the same, the PHP file is served and I get the prompt to save it from the browser. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: `nginx works great for plain html` nginx just serves HTML, it's your browser that parses it. `PHP-FPM setup listening on 127.0.0.1:9000 properly` I guess its not really proper if it does not work. How did you install nginx + php?

Comment: place your `location` block inside the `server` block. Location has no use when declared inside `http`

Comment: `apt-get install php5-fpm` + `apt-get install nginx`? What I'm saying is that I've checked and php is listening on that port.

Comment: @foibs Placed location block inside server, reloaded & restarded nginx, problem isn't fixed.

Comment: @user3037184 okay, but the file saved contains the php code or the generated html code?

Comment: @user3037184 This means that php-fpm does not come into effect. Check your location blocks again. Update your question if necessary

Comment: but where is the server block? Is it in sites-enabled? Are there more servers in there who could be taking the request? This configuration seems correct, but there is something more that we don't see and causing the issue

Comment: I know, it has been driving me nuts, there is no additional files in sites-enabled, everything seems to be pointing to the right direction, nginx error logs don't give a clue. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: how about if you delete this `index  index.php index.html index.htm;`?

Comment: Doesn't help, same thing.

Comment: Is there a way I could debug this more in depth? E.g. if  the php file is even passed to fastcgi?

Comment: The php file is not passed to fastcgi, that's why you keep getting the file like this. Look for nginx's `access_log`. You can show all sorts of variables in there. Also php-fpm has it's own access log (you may have to edit the conf to enable it). Good luck. I give up

Comment: If you ask me, I'd reduce the php block to just the `include` then the `fastcgi_pass` under it. 2 lines only. usually works for me.

Comment: Thanks @foibs and @Mohammad, I have reinstalled nginx and everything seems to work so I have reduced the problem to my custom compiled nginx code (*sigh* should have mentioned it in retrospect), I have redownloaded the source of the same version that worked for me and compiled with `#sudo ./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin --without-http_gzip_module` `make` and `checkinstall`, all the files are replaced and I can confirm that my custom compiled nginx is running except that PHP doesn't work for it (same configs and everything).