# Compiled nginx doesn't work with PHP

Tags: nginx, php

I have a properly installed (apt-get) nginx that works perfectly with html and php but when I download the source of the same version (I don't modify it for testing purposes), I configure it with `sudo ./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin --without-http_gzip_module` then make, install, reload and restart it all the PHP files stop working, they are being served as binary so the browser prompts to save them, HTML files continue to be served properly.

Any insights on where to start debugging this issue? All the configs remained the same from the working version, the only difference is that .php files don't work.

Comment: Could you update your question and post your Nginx config?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nginx serves raw php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221966/nginx-serves-raw-php)